# Timeout error when running tests on Meteor demo app

Tags: meteor, mocha.js

I'm having an `Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test` error when I try to run tests on Meteor demo app: https://github.com/meteor/todos [(guide)](https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html#running-unit-tests)

When I run `TEST_WATCH=1 meteor test --driver-package meteortesting:mocha` I get the following failed test:

> 17 passing (4s)
>
> 1 failing
>
> 1) todos publications todos.inList sends no todos for a private list
>   when not logged in:
>
> Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded.
>
> Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.

The same error happens on an app I'm developing so I can't run any integration tests.

I'm running Meteor 1.7.0.1 in the todos app and mongodb version 3.6.8, in Ubuntu 18.04.

The same project runs tests okay in my partner computers who is running the same meteor and mongodb version, but on OSX.

setting this.timeout(15000) inside tests does nothing. Also tried MOCHA_TIMEOUT environment variable with same results. Just can't modify the 2s timeout

Comment: This means the async callback `done` is neither called blank nor with an error parameter. You may need to debug the test unit for further insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated `meteortesting:mocha-core` to latest version and now MOCHA_TIMEOUT is being recognized, set it to 5s and now it works.